# Why is my Bluetooth on a RTL8723BE not working?

Tags: debian, bluetooth, realtek

I'm using Debian, a Realtek RTL8723BE Wificard with Bluetooth and the firmware from 
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_bt.

But if I run

```
hcitool dev
```

I get

```
Devices:
So there is no device found.
```

But the firmware is correctly loaded:

```
$ dmesg | grep hci
Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06  lmp_subver=8723
Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
Bluetooth: hci0: extension section signature mismatch
```

I get this message is twice in the output of demsg, what means

```
Bluetooth: hci0: extension section signature mismatch
```

Bluetooth isn't blocked to:

```
# rfkill list
[...]
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    blocked: no
    blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: Try this. See if there is a package called tlp installed on our system. If yes, remove it and reboot. This should fix your problem. You can also block the device in tlp instead. Works in Manjaro, read https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bluetooth-adapter-cannot-be-turned-on-realtek-rtl8723be/10130/32?u=aditya for details

Comment: Thank you, but I dont have the device anymore so I cant try. But maybe it helps other people experiencing those issues

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Debian Jessie (8.3) and I have also the Realtek RTL8723BE device. The Realtek RTL8723BE device includes wifi and bluetooth support. In my case, wifi had to be deactivated in order to make a bluetooth connection possible. However, I'm using the bluetooth driver from  http://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git.